# error in running phoenix example

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I've integrated my hadoop2 and hbase0.98 with phoenix and by typing command `sqlline.py localhost` phoenix shell starts, but when I try to run apache phoenix example by this command : `psql.py /usr/local/phoenix/examples/WEB_STAT.sql /usr/local/phoenix/examples/WEB_STAT.csv /usr/local/phoenix/examples/WEB_STAT_QUERIES.sql` I faced this error `ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.`

I use hadoop 2.6 in single mode and hbase 0.98 in psudo distributed mod, in addition I didn't explicitly install zookeeper, is it required to install zookeeper explicitly?

my HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-site.xml file contains :

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hduser/hbase/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master</name> 
    <value>hadoop-master:60000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and my running java process are

```
7415 DataNode
7262 NameNode
9119 Jps
7605 SecondaryNameNode
7893 NodeManager
8704 HRegionServer
8544 HMaster
8475 HQuorumPeer
7763 ResourceManager
```

Comment: HBase failed to start. Check the HBase logs and post them here.

Comment: I think HBase is running because I can run HBase shell

Comment: In addition I can run command : `sqlline.py localhost` and create table in HBase using Phoenix but when I want to run command `psql.py /usr/local/phoenix/examples/WEB_STAT.sql /usr/local/phoenix/examples/WEB_STAT.csv /usr/local/phoenix/examples/WEB_STAT_QUERIES.sql` it errors!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you should add the address of your server here `localhost` to your command. Pay attention to command you've already run, `sqlline.py localhost` that you gave the server address.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the HDP distribution? iirc they use `/hbase-unsecure` or for un-Kerberized clusters. I don't remember how it interacted with your config setting for `/hbase`

1. start the ZooKeeper cli

`zkCli.sh` or perhaps some variant of `zookeepershell`

2. query the existing root nodes
   `ls /`
3. the HBase root node is probably named `hbase-unsecure`

Comment: I use Hadoop 2.6 in singlemode type and HBase. I didn't install zookeeper seperately and I think HBase itself include required hbase. As you can see `8475 HQuorumPeer` is running in my machine.

Comment: Regardless of how ZooKeeper was installed, you need to run the ZooKeeper shell to see the name of the hbase node.